# integrals in Hopf algebras

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, hopf-algebras

Let $H$ be a Hopf algebra and $g$ be a group-like element in
$H^{*}$. Define $L_{g}=\{x\in H\mid hx=g(h)x,~\forall h\in H\}$. If $H$
is not semisimple, when can we find a group-like element $g$ in
$H^{*}$ such that $g(L_{g})\neq 0$ ?